# W3 total cache, cron empty Object Cache

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

I'm using w3-total-cache on wordpress with wooCommerce.

I had to activate the Object Cache because of the slow .

Being the site very large and old, in a week I create up to 4GB of cache and over 350,000 files.

I used:

```
if( class_exists('W3_Plugin_TotalCacheAdmin') )
{
    $plugin_totalcacheadmin = & w3_instance('W3_Plugin_TotalCacheAdmin');
    $plugin_totalcacheadmin->flush_all();
}
```

But still goes into max_execution_time, and I cannot change the php.ini.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

better to activate server caching instead of using any caching plugins

To turn caching off/On, you will need to login to WHM then go to EasyApache4
From there, if you wish to disable caching, you need to provision "cPanel Default" 
If you wish to enable caching, you need to provision "All PHP Options + OpCache "